# bundler: failed to load command: rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to Rails and I want to run Rspec using Mac.

When I run:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/00_hello_spec.rb
```

I get the following response:

```
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- spec_helper
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `require'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `block in requires='
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `each'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1181:in `requires='
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:110:in `block in process_options_into'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `each'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `process_options_into'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
  /Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

Please help with any suggestions or clarification on this issue. To add, I have done this at various level of the file system from root upward. I highly appreciate any clarifications to help me out of my dilemma.

Comment: Did you run `rails generate rspec:install`?

Comment: Does the file `spec/spec_helper.rb` exist? This file normally gets auto-generated, but if you could easily add it manually.

Comment: The very first line of your file `spec/00_hello_spec.rb` probably says `require "spec_helper"`, and the file does not exist. That is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I added the spec_helper using 'rspec --init'. Now it saying this:bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/Users/OumouKaba/Downloads/test-first-ruby-master/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec)
NoMethodError: undefined method `shared_context_metadata_behavior=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fdc263c6630>

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone. With your suggestions and so googled tips, I was able finally get it working.

Comment: > I was able to get it working

What was the command which accomplished this?

Comment: This kind of comment - "Oh, never mind, I figured it out" - is ridiculously unhelpful for anyone else who finds this question later after searching the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue in the future try to see if you have multiple versions of  different *rspec* gems installed, like so:

```
gem list | grep rspec
```

In case you do, delete the gem's version that don't match what you have in your *Gemfile.lock*, like so:

```
gem uninstall <gem_name> <gem_version>
```

After following those steps I was able to successfully run `rspec spec`!